# How do the "random" generators in different languages (i.e. Java and C++) compare?

Tags: java, c++, random

Despite the weird title, I wish to ask a legitimate question: which method's generated numbers are more *random*: Java's `Random()` class or `Math.random()`, or C++'s `rand()`?

I've heard that PHP's `rand()` is quite bad, i.e. if you map its results you can clearly see a pattern; sadly, I don't know how to draw a map in C++ or Java.

Also, just out of interest, what about C#?

Comment: C++ has `<random>`. I think I read once, though it might be totally bogus memory, that C# uses a MT.

Comment: Seeing patterns is natural for the human mind. In fact I'd be worried about the randomness of the random function if you DIDN'T see patterns. 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 MAY be quite a bit more random than 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0

Comment: @BasvandenBroek : the probleme here is that the pattern is predictable. It's not juste a chunk, it's the full random sequence.

Comment: Define 'more random'. The difference between them is generally the period length of whatever is being used as a generator. Apparently `java.util.Random` uses a linear congruential generator, similarly with `rand` in C. C++11 introduces `mt19937` (Mersenne Twister) among other things. They're all deterministic under the hood (hence the Pseudo in PRNG) though.

Comment: Javas Math class uses the Random class so they are the same.

Comment: After the few standard statements on random number generators, this will dissolve into a C++ vs. Java discussion.

Comment: @Thomas Why would it? This rarely happens here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Get a few thousands numbers generated by those languages and test them with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both Java and C++ generate pseudo-random numbers which are either:

- adequate to the task for anyone who isn't a statistician or cryptographer <sup>(a)</sup>; or
- woefully inadequate to those two classes of people.

In all honesty, unless you *are* in one of those classes, pseudo-random number generators are fine.

Java also has `SecureRandom` which purports to provide crypto-class non-determinism (I can't comment on the veracity of that argument) and C++ now has a much wider variety of random number generation capability than just `rand()` - see [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) for details.

Specific operating systems may provides sources of entropy for random number generators such as [`CryptGenRandom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379942.aspx) under Windows or reading `/dev/random` under Linux. Alternatively, you could add entropy by using random events such as user input timing.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> May actually contain traces of other job types that aren't statistician or cryptographer :-)

Comment: There exists <random> header file in C++11 which provides a whole host of functions for distributions and random number generators. So the support for C++ seems robust. I don't know about Java though.

Answer (score 5):

`java.util.Random` (which is used internally by `Math.random()`) uses a [Linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), which is a rather weak RNG, but enough for simple things. For important applications, one should use `java.security.SecureRandom` instead.

I don't think the C or C++ language specifications proscribe the algorithm to use for `rand()` but most implementations use a LCG as well. C++11 has added new APIs that yield higher-quality randomness.

Comment: This has changed significantly with C++11. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: @juanchopanza: new APIs were added, but the algorithm for rand() is still unspecified.

Comment: Right, but the point is that there is now much more than just `rand()`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a very good document that can be found on the web, done by one of the worldwide experts in random number generators.

[Here is the document](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/testu01.pdf)

The first part of the document is a description of the tests, which you might skip unless your really interested. From page 27, there are the results of the different tests for many generators, including Java, C++, Matlab, Mathematica, Excel, Boost,... (They are described in the text).

It seems that the generator of Java is a bit better, but both are not among the best in the world. The MT19937 from C++11 is already much better.

Comment: Page 27, I think you may have got the page# from "Article 22 / 27" but _every_ page has the 22 on it. Changed that for you :-) In any case, +1 for finding some hard data.

Answer (score 0):

PHP uses a seed. If the seed is the same at two different times, the rand() function will ALWAYS output the same thing. (Which can be quite bad for tokens for example).
I don't know for C++ and Java, but there's no true randomness, which makes quality difficult to evaluate. Security musn't rely on such functions.

Comment: it's same everywhere. all math algorithms are deterministic, and given the same seed produce the same output. truly random numbers can only be produced just software.

Comment: I totally agree, and that's what I just said.

Comment: Quite irrelevant. The standard has always been to seed with the current time. Provided that that has sufficient resolution and the PRNG is sufficiently dependent on its seed, this is robust for many applications. Even security, if the time=seed cannot be guessed by the adversary.

Comment: Imagine we use the microtime() function for the seed, as many programmers do (`mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);`), there are many ways to create a vulnerability (see http://www.suspekt.org/2008/08/17/mt_srand-and-not-so-random-numbers/ for example)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any language where random numbers are truly random - I'm sure such a thing exists, but generally, it's "You stick a seed in, and you get the sequence that seed gives". Which is fine if you want to make a simple 'shootem-up' game, basic poker-game, roulette simulator for home use, etc. But if you have money relying on the game being truly random (e.g., you are giving out money based on the results of certain sequences) or your secret files are relying on your random numbers, then you will definitely need some other mechanism for finding random numbers.

And there are some "true" random number generators around. They do not provide a seed, so predictability based on what number(s) you got last time is low. I'm not saying it's zero, because I'm not sure you can get that even from sampling radio waves at an unused radio frequency, radioactive decay or whatever the latest method of genearing true random numbers is.